# Оптимизация left join запроса (mssql) для больших таблиц

Tags: sql-server, оптимизация-запросов

Как можно оптимизировать ниже приведенный запрос? Кол-во записей в таблице > 14 миллионов.

Пример исходных данных для 'XVG/BTC', 'XRP/BTC', 'XMR/BTC' за период с 1 по 3 июля доступны [тут](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mPodUL6Mc9ko39L6-ZtQ2FzRKOqfm8Y5/view?usp=sharing)

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[v_agg_day_trades] WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT 
        LEFT(a.pair, CHARINDEX('/', a.pair)-1) Base,
        SUBSTRING(a.pair, CHARINDEX('/', a.pair)+1, 20) Quote,      
        a.pair as Pair,
        CAST(a.dt AS DATE) [date], 
        ROUND(AVG(100 * (CASE WHEN a.price > b.price THEN a.price / b.price - 1 WHEN a.price < b.price THEN b.price / a.price - 1 ELSE null END )), 8) PriceStep, 
        ROUND(MIN(a.price), 8) MinPrice,
        ROUND(MAX(a.price), 8) MaxPrice,
        ROUND(AVG(a.price), 8) AvgPrice,
        SUM(a.amount) BaseDayVolume,
        AVG(a.amount) BaseAvgVolume,
        MIN(a.amount) BaseMinVolume,
        MAX(a.amount) BaseMaxVolume,
        SUM(a.cost) QuoteDayVolume,
        AVG(a.cost) QuoteAvgVolume,
        MIN(a.cost) QuoteMinVolume,
        MAX(a.cost) QuoteMaxVolume,
        COUNT(*) Transactions
FROM dbo.trades a WITH(NOLOCK, NOWAIT) LEFT HASH JOIN dbo.trades b WITH(NOLOCK, NOWAIT) ON a.pair = b.pair AND a.tid + 1 = b.tid  AND a.side != b.side
GROUP BY 
        LEFT(a.pair, CHARINDEX('/', a.pair)-1),
        SUBSTRING(a.pair, CHARINDEX('/', a.pair)+1, 20),        
        a.pair, 
        cast(a.dt as date)

GO
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[trades](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [pair] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [dt] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [ts] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [tid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [side] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [price] [float] NULL,
    [amount] [float] NULL,
    [cost] [float] NULL,
    [fee] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


USE [tb5]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

/****** Object:  Index [ClusteredIndex-20200729-004955]    Script Date: 8/1/2020 09:54:42 ******/
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ClusteredIndex-20200729-004955] ON [dbo].[trades]
(
    [pair] ASC,
    [ts] ASC,
    [tid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Перенести в проседуру и разбить на временные таблицы. Я так понимаю у вас считает средним по дням. Нужно уменьшить количество дней для расчета. Одним словом оптимизация не поможет если много записей

Comment: А с одним pair много значений ? Если да, то попробуйте сделать индекс `create index trades_i on(pair, tid) include(side, price)`. И кстати, что такое tid ? у вас случаем связка pair, tid не уникальна ? Если да, то может быть можно переписать на один проход по таблице с оконными функциями

Comment: А еще, я думаю это мелочь, но можно попробовать убрать из group by первые 2 функции, a.pair целиком достаточно, что бы не надо было вычислять эти функции при группировке

Comment: @Mike tid -  transaction id (autoincrement) для каждой пары  eth/btc = tid => 1,2,3, etc,  ltc/btc => 1,2,3. связка pair,tid уникальна.  Как для этой цели использовать оконную функцию?  Суть текущего скрипта собрать статистику по каждой паре на каждый день и для этого вполнего хватило бы одной таблицы. Но есть подзадача. нужно в течении каждого дня найти среднее процентное отклонение между ценой продажи и покупки, но берутся не все транзакции, а только если за покупкой идет сразу продажа (по tid) или за продаже сразу покупка. Случаи  покупка покупка или продажа продажа исключаются.

Comment: Сначала select *, + заглядываете вперед `lead(price) over(partition by pair order by tid)` и то же для side (и возможно для tid, если вдруг может быть пропуск и надо проконтролировать что он именно +1) сравниваете сразу case price, только с доп условиями на side != lead(side), оборачиваете во внешний запрос и группируете. как то так, сложно говорить точнее не видя данных и не до конца понимая требуемое

Comment: @Mike - добавил примеры исходны данных. Не совсем понял как проверять лидом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обновил код с учетом рекомендаций @Mike.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[v_agg_day_trades] WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
WITH q  AS (

    SELECT LEFT(pair, CHARINDEX('/', pair)-1) Base, SUBSTRING(pair, CHARINDEX('/', pair)+1, 20) Quote, pair, CAST(dt AS DATE) [date], 
        price,  
        LEAD(price,1) OVER(PARTITION BY pair ORDER BY tid) next_price, 
        side,
        LEAD(side,1) OVER(PARTITION BY pair ORDER BY tid) next_side, amount, cost
    FROM dbo.trades WITH(NOLOCK, NOWAIT)
) 
SELECT  Base, Quote, pair, [date],
        ROUND(MIN(q.price), 8) MinPrice,
        ROUND(MAX(q.price), 8) MaxPrice,
        ROUND(AVG(q.price), 8) AvgPrice,
        ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN NOT (side = next_side OR price = next_price) THEN ROUND(100*ABS(price/next_price - 1),4) ELSE NULL END), 4) priceStep, 
        SUM(q.amount) BaseDayVolume,
        AVG(q.amount) BaseAvgVolume,
        MIN(q.amount) BaseMinVolume,
        MAX(q.amount) BaseMaxVolume,
        SUM(q.cost) QuoteDayVolume,
        AVG(q.cost) QuoteAvgVolume,
        MIN(q.cost) QuoteMinVolume,
        MAX(q.cost) QuoteMaxVolume
FROM q
GROUP BY Base, Quote, pair, [date]
```

---

```
/****** Object:  Index [NonClusteredIndex-20200801-213918]    Script Date: 8/1/2020 21:56:38 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NonClusteredIndex-20200801-213918] ON [dbo].[trades]
(
    [pair] ASC,
    [tid] ASC
)
INCLUDE([side],[price],[dt],[ts],[amount],[cost],[fee]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

---

```
/****** Object:  Index [ClusteredIndex-20200729-004955]    Script Date: 8/1/2020 21:57:28 ******/
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ClusteredIndex-20200729-004955] ON [dbo].[trades]
(
    [pair] ASC,
    [ts] ASC,
    [tid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Ситуация намного улучшилась, но для больших данных (145 890 265 строк), запрос медленный.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну 145 млн конечно медленно поднимать с диска. С этим ничего сделать нельзя.  Чудес не бывает. только делать таблицу, в которой будут храниться уже агрегированные данные. И обновлять ее либо триггерами, либо дозаполнять когда данные нужны

Comment: Думал индекс сделать на вьюшку, но нельзя из-за подзапроса